# MongoDB update() is actually replacing the whole record in my code

Tags: php, mongodb

I am updating my MongoDB database using the form data coming from a PHP script and it can have variable number of elements to be updated into MongoDB. For testing purpose, I tried..

```
$update = '"continent"=>"Asia"'; // one element to be updated, would be multiple eventually

$tracking->sessions->update(array("ts"=>$timestamp,"fb_id"=>$fb_id),array($update));
```

I do not get any error when I do this, however the data is not updated in the database, the record is actually REPLACED with this one:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("517048f87a088a7e65000003"), "0" : "'continent'=>'Asia'" }
```

Original record:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("517048f87a088a7e65000003"), "fb_id" : "123456", "ts" : "1366316915", "continent" : "North America", "city" : "New York" }
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you told it to update the matched document to be the passed in document.

If you only intended to set specific fields you need to [use the $set operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/).

Comment: Good catch! :)
I added the $set operator, however the data is not updated in the database. Please find my updated code.

Comment: Sorry, I had a stupid typo in my code. Its my bad!

Comment: The order of elements in the MongoDB record is changed though. The last updated element appears first. How do I fix this?

Comment: order of fields is not guaranteed - is it important?

Comment: yes, because I am generating the HTML form using this order. Is there a way to fix it?